# If hasClass then removeClass on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have an image gallery.
When I click on it, the images stand out because the body background goes from white to black.

When I click again on the image it goes back to normal.

This is what I have for now :

```
$('img').click(function () {
  $('body').toggleClass("darken");
});
```

I'd like my users to be able to click anywhere on the page and remove the class "darken".

I tried the hasClass statement but with no success.

```
if ($('body').hasClass('darken')) {
        $('body').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("darken");
    });
    }
```

Thank you very much,
Clément.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the click event handler to `<body>`. But, be sure to stop the propagation of the click event on `img`.

```
var $body = $("body"), $img = $("img");

$img.click(function(evt) {
  $body.toggleClass("darken");
  evt.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
  $body.removeClass("darken");
});
```

Comment: Possibly the easiest way to do what OP required. Kudos!

Comment: Works like a charm. Live result here : http://bettercheckthekids.com/polar-2 Many thanks Alexander!

Comment: Seems like there is a little hiccup when I reclick on any of the image. Especially when you get to the last image. Do you notice it too?

Comment: Well, I replaced ('body') by ('*'). Suits my need just fine.

Comment: @cfocket, I believe it's a really bad idea to use `$("*")`. I didn't notice any hiccup when I saw it though

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $body = $( 'body' ); 
    if(e.target.id && e.target.id === 'menu-btn') $body.toggleClass( 'navigation-opened' );
    else if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'nav') $body.removeClass( 'navigation-opened' );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be more shorthand, but will do the same:

```
$('body.darker').live('click', function() { $(this).removeClass('darker'); } )
```

Comment: Usage of `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: Alexander, you're right! It should be rewritten to something like this: `$(document).on('click', 'body.darker', function() { $(this).removeClass('darker'); } );`  I was just used to the .live function :-)   For reference: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Sorry man, didn't get the chance to try your solution. Cheers